# Order array in div columns with PHP modulus

Tags: php, foreach, modulo

Who can help me with the solution to order an array into different divs with PHP modulus?
I have an array with categories and use an foreach loop to display te items but I want order these in 3 columns.

For example I have the following categories

- Books
- Cars
- Games
- Movies
- Music
- Office

the output what I want is

```
<div class="column-1">
    <span>Books</span>
    <span>Cars</span>
</div>
<div class="column-2">
    <span>Games</span>
    <span>Movies</span>
</div>
<div class="column-3">
    <span>Music</span>
    <span>Office</span>
</div>
```

How can I set these 3 columns with modulus?

Comment: Boils down to simple math. Your column value matches the modulo of 3 for 1 and 2. All you need is a condition checking if it's zero, then use 3 instead.

Comment: What if you had 8 values? What would the output look like?